# Video format that can be played while recording?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, ffmpeg, video-player

I want to make a kind of server-client software which would support live webcam. My approach is to record webcam to an avi on hard disk while transfering each fresh byte of that avi to the other peer who will play it till the most recent byte that is transfered. But of course, avi failed to be played while file is being recorded.

My question is : is there any video/audio format out there that suite my need, to be playable while being recorded ?

I've tried around with ffmpeg for a while, and I wonder if "ffplay" which is always included with ffmpeg can do the trick? ( very few documentatons & examples about ffplay could be found)

PS: I'm using MS built-in function MCISendString to play video, and any 3rd party component would be welcomed as well as any suggestion!

Comment: there are several that can play as *they are being streamed* but as they are being recorded by a third party lib seems pretty dubious: lots of encoders play or preview as they process but often ffmpeg processing is a two step process using an interim file.

Comment: Thanks! I think my words were not clear, I mean playable while streaming. So could you plese point out some of the format & the corresponding method to play the stream?

Answer (score 0):

FLV and mpeg2 transport streams both meet your requirements.